# React-router gives 401 when using class components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router v6.8.1. When I try to access a route with a url like localhost:3000/customers it gives 401 when using a class component.

Here is the codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-morning-iqrewo

```
{"errors":{"detail":"Unauthorized"}}
```

If I use a function component I can access the compoent without problems.

Here is the router code

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Payments searchParams={searchParams} navigate={navigate} />} />
  <Route path="/customers" element={<Customers searchParams={searchParams} navigate={navigate} />} />
  <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
</Routes>
```

Users component is a function components so I can access it via url. But I can neither access Customers component via Url nor refresh the page when in customers page.
There is no problem while navigation via RouterLink. The problem occurs only if I enter url manually.

This is the router in index.tsx file

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
...
<Router>
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>
</Router>
```

I am using "react-scripts start" command to run the app in local.

This is the users component

```
const Users: FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Box className="centered-flex" sx={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
             Users List
        </Box>
    );
};
```

and this is the customers component

```
class Customers extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  private filterRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
    };
  }
```

Comment: React components are React components, from the JSX standpoint it doesn't really matter how a component is implemented, and from a `Route`'s `element` prop standpoint it doesn't/shouldn't matter at all. Servers are what return 401 status errors though, not anything a React app is rendering. Can you [edit] the post to include more relevant details, like how you are running and serving the app?

Comment: I added some more detail. I know it shouldn't matter if the component is a class component or not but when I change Customers component to functional it doesn't give the same error

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for still using React class-based components? Would it be possible for you to create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Why shouldn't I use the class components? I use lifecycle methods and I need lots of state management and it is done easier with class components. I don't think I can create a demo. It is not a personal project. If you want more details I can share with you

Comment: Class components, for all intents and purposes, were effectively deprecated when React hooks were released. Are you saying that after fully replicating the `Customers` component as a function component everything worked as expected? If that's not a reason to ditch class components I don't know what is. Is it possible you didn't do a 100% conversion and there's something in the class-based component causing a problem? We kind of need a [mcve] to dig in any further.

Comment: I added a codesandbox demo. I couldn't reproduce the error in the demo but it may give you and idea about what is wrong